# Reproduce Mann-Whitney U in Excel

Tags: python, excel, scipy, p-value, scipy.stats

I am trying to calculate Mann-Whitney test in Excel, but I get different results from those of [`scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.6.3/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html#scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu) when I try to apply the continuity correction.

For example, I have the following data:

- 2015 observations: 2,2,5,1,2,2,2,4,2,4,5,4,2,1,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,1,4,3,1,3,4,3,5,1
- 2016 observations: 2,1,2,5,5,1,5,3,2,1,2,5,5,2,4,4,3,1,2,2,1,3,3,1,2,5,1,4,3,5

And I use the following code:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu([2,2,5,1,2,2,2,4,2,4,5,4,2,1,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,1,4,3,1,3,4,3,5,1], 
                         [2,1,2,5,5,1,5,3,2,1,2,5,5,2,4,4,3,1,2,2,1,3,3,1,2,5,1,4,3,5], 
                         use_continuity=False)
```

I got the following results:

- Python: statistic=416.5, pvalue=0.3053664240420257
- Excel:  statistic=416.5, pvalue=0.305366424042026

so they are equal.

But when I write **`use_continuity=True`** I get the following results:

- Python: *statistic=416.5, **pvalue=0.30803418957886164**
- Excel:  *statistic=416.5,  **pvalue=0.302708955583188**

When I put **`use_continuity=-1`** I get the following:

- Python: statistic=416.5, **pvalue=0.30270895558318833**
- Excel:  statistic=416.5, **pvalue=0.308034189578862**

As you see, I get opposite results in Excel and Python. According to [the implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.3/scipy/stats/stats.py#L7090-L7185), `use_continuity` is used like

```py
meanrank = n1*n2/2.0 + 0.5 * use_continuity
```

is there any possibility that implementation is incorrect and it should be

```py
meanrank = n1*n2/2.0 - 0.5 * use_continuity
```

?

Or maybe you have other ideas why I do not get the same results?

Answer (score 0):

The continuity correction implementation in SciPy was *not* correct, as discussed in [`scipy/scipy#2118`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2118). What *should* happen is for the correction to nudge the test statistic toward the mean of the asymptotic distribution, slightly increasing the p-value to compensate for the discrete nature of the exact distribution. Since this question was posted, `mannwhitneyu` has been rewritten, and the new implementation of the continuity correction is available [`here`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/stats/_mannwhitneyu.py#L183-L188).

Also, note that `use_continuity=-1` never should have been allowed; that was a bug, too.